# How can I use the browser on Linux or Windows as my GUI

Tags: windows, linux, user-interface

Is there a way to create an app on Linux or Windows using the browser as a GUI? Basically I will have simple forms on the browser that will get input from the user display the result after processing the input.

So I need something that the user click as an app, the app will automatically opens up a browser and start interacting with the user

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com), it has a WebKit widget, that is a full featured browser. You could then point the initial load url to your html and do what you need.

Qt is portable and a simple recompile would enable that simple app to work on Linux, Windows, Mac and more.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood, you wish to have your own application and hook up a browser inside it? I have done this using wxWidgets and Mozilla xulrunner. It was rather easy, IIRC I got it all working in an hour or so. You need to set up wxWidgets and then wxWebConnect:

http://www.wxwidgets.com

http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect/documentation/getting-started.html

This would get you full functionality with CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your application act as a web server, then spawn off a browser and point it to your server. You can then send it whatever html+css+javascript that you want.

Comment: This, plus a URL-shortcut, sounds like what Sara is looking for.